# need to restrict relationship using foreign key

Tags: python, django

I'm Brazilian then in the table Veiculo == vehicle and Pessoa == person
and as a person can have several cars plus one car only one person, when registering a new monthly checkin in the parking lot, I need to select the person only the cars that he own appear as an option.
I need that when registering a Pessoa and a Veiculo they are realacionamos in a way that when registering using Views Mensalista when I put Pessoa soment the Veiculo that is owned by it appears

Models.py

```
STATE_CHOICES = (
    ('AC', 'Acre'), ('AL', 'Alagoas'), ('AP', 'Amapá'),
    ('AM', 'Amazonas'), ('BA', 'Bahia'), ('CE', 'Ceará'),
    ('DF', 'Distrito Federal'), ('ES', 'Espírito Santo'),
    ('GO', 'Goiás'), ('MA', 'Maranhão'), ('MT', 'Mato Grosso'),
    ('MS', 'Mato Grosso do Sul'), ('MG', 'Minas Gerais'),
    ('PA', 'Pará'), ('PB', 'Paraíba'), ('PR', 'Paraná'),
    ('PE', 'Pernambuco'), ('PI', 'Piauí'), ('RJ', 'Rio de Janeiro'),
    ('RN', 'Rio Grande do Norte'), ('RS', 'Rio Grande do Sul'),
    ('RO', 'Rondônia'), ('RR', 'Roraima'), ('SC', 'Santa Catarina'),
    ('SP', 'São Paulo'), ('SE', 'Sergipe'), ('TO', 'Tocantins')
)


class Pessoa(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=False)
    cpf = models.CharField(max_length=11, unique=True, blank=False)
    endereco = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    numero = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    bairro = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    telefone = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False)
    cidade = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    estado = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=STATE_CHOICES)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.nome) + ' - ' + str(self.email) 


class Veiculo(models.Model):
    marca = models.ForeignKey(Marca, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False)
    modelo = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False)
    ano = models.CharField(max_length=7)
    placa = models.CharField(max_length=7)
    proprietario = models.ForeignKey(
        Pessoa, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False, )
    cor = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=False)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.modelo + ' - ' + self.placa
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def mensalista_novo(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MensalistaForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('core_lista_mensalista')
    else:
        form = MensalistaForm
    return render(request, 'core/lista_mensalistas.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: explain more please, what do you want to do?

Comment: I'm Brazilian then in the table Veiculo == vehicle and Pessoa == person
and as a person can have several cars plus one car only one person, when registering a new monthly checkin in the parking lot, I need to select the person only the cars that he own appear as an option.

Answer (score 0):

if you want cars of a person, you can use this filter :

```
proprietarioId = id
queryList = Veiculo.objects.filter(proprietario__id = proprietarioId)
```

Comment: Sorry I'm newbie, but this code I put in view, or in models?
I need them to be inserted into an input.
Example, when I select the name of the person and another input it loads the vehicles of that person